# How to insert random integers in a binary search tree

Tags: java, random, binary-search-tree

For my homework I'm creating a code that generates one thousand random integers from a set of 10,000 numbers, moves them into a container, and then into a binary search tree. I'm given the following code first:

```
Random ran = new Random();
Integer x;{  
for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
x = ran.nextInt(10,000) + 1;
}
```

I have a BSTNode & an Intclass. Given the following code in the BST class, I can use this to search

```
public boolean search(Integer value) {
    boolean retval = false;
    numofcomps ++;
    if (root == null) {
        retval = false;
    } else {
        retval = searchtree(root, value);
    }
    return retval;
}

public boolean searchtree(BSTNode<IntClass> myroot, int value) {
    numofcomps ++;
    boolean retval = false;
    if (myroot == null) {
        retval = false;
    } else {
        if (value == myroot.element.myInt) {
            retval = true;
        } else {
            if (value < myroot.element.myInt) {
                retval = searchtree(myroot.leftTree, value);
            } else {
                retval = searchtree(myroot.rightTree, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to figure out how to move the random numbers into the binary tree. Any suggestions?

Comment: What you're describing is an insertion operation. Search 'how to insert into a BST'.

Comment: You have some `search` methods, so where is your `insert` method?

Comment: You would want to build a `Tree` class composed of `Nodes` and use and insert method where you're inserting a `Node` into your `Tree` with the `Node` having a value of the random `int`. Insert behaves similar to search. So you're off to a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert element recursively in this manner. It assumes that you have those setters and getters defined, but you could change that to fit your specific interface needs easily.

```
public void insert(int val) {
    if (this.myRoot == null) {
        this.myRoot = new BSTNode<Integer>(val);
    } else {
        insert(this.myRoot, val);
    }
}

private void insert(BSTNode<Integer> node, int val) {
    if (val < node.getVal()) {
        if (node.getLeftChild() == null) {
            node.setLeftChild(new BSTNode<Integer>(val));
        } else {
            insert(node.getLeftChild(), val);
        }
    } else {
        if (node.getRightChild() == null) {
            node.setRightChild(new BSTNode<Integer>(val));
        } else {
            insert(node.getRightChild(), val);
        }
    }
}
```